# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError "Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap"

Tags: android, maui, .net-maui

I'm brand new to dot net MAUI and Android development in general.

I'm trying to call an existing .aar library from a maui android application. The .aar came from an android studio java project (Kvaser canlib android 1.2.0, https://www.kvaser.com/download/). I have the source code for the library, and I was able to build it in Android Studio, to generate the aar. The android studio project consists of an app, as well as the library. The provided app seems to run well enough and calls the library without trouble.

I'd like to use the AAR from a MAUI app. I created an "Android Java Library Binding" for the AAR, and it seems to build ok. I can see everything I expect in the vs2022 object explorer. When I first go to use the library from a MAUI app, I get an exception of "Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError", "Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap".

From some Googling, my best guess is that it might be a problem with the android support library v4 (or lack thereof)? I tried to add Xamarin.Support.v4 nuget package, but got yet more exotic errors with low google search results (MSB4018, The "VerifyVersionsTask" task failed unexpectedly).

The AAR's android studio project was set up with the following sdk versions:

```
compileSdkVersion = 23
targetSdkVersion = 23
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersionCanLib = 12
minSdkVersionApp = 16
```

Also, in the android studio project dependancies:

```
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
api 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
```

The android studio project, upon first opening form Kvaser's website, prompted me to upgrade gradle multiple times, until it seemed happy enough to build at V5.4.1.

My vs2022 version: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1

I've tried lots of things but I'm not sure how much or relevant to describe here. Please let me know if I've missed anything that would be helpful. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this NoClassDefFoundError?

I've posted this question also to the .net maui github discussion board at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7652, where I've also attached my source code.

Comment: `api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` - See in [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) - those are deprecated. AFAIK, what is needed for Maui is [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx). I *think* that means you need a version of AAR that is compatible with AndroidX (not appcompat-...). Maybe someone else will see your question, and be more knowledgeable about what you need to do.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks a lot for the input. I has a suspicion that upgrading to AndroidX may be a potential fix. I started down that path and quickly ran into some complications that required a little more effort that I though was prudent. Especially since I had no idea if it would ultimately fix my problem. But your comment is enough for me to take another stab at that.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, you were right, upgrading the AAR to use AndroidX, did allow the library to work seamlessly (so far anyway) in MAUI. I found the 'Refactor -> Migrate To AndroidX' command in Android Studio worked pretty well without too 
 much headache. I also tried Jetifier, but it didn't work. I had tried the migrate command before but got a ton of errors. I think the min/target/build api versions eemd to come into play - I last time i had different settings. Thanks again.